# How can i find the value of Planck's constant using Black body radiation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, thermal-radiation, home-experiment, physical-constants

I'm working for a physics project for Highschool, and i'm currently thinking about using black body radiation to measure Planck's constant. I know there is an option using the photoelectric effect but i'm more interested in black body radiation. Is it possible for a highschool student to even go about this experiment?

Comment: it is hard . have a look at this http://eprints.bice.rm.cnr.it/22120/1/ncc12554.pdf